# Access naming values

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I got a field [Grade] with several possible values : 1 , 1.5 , 2 , 2.5 , 3 , ... , 5.5 ,6

I need to add a new field to a query, named "Grades verbally" with the following criteria:

```
    if Grade <2 F else
    if Grade <3 E else
    if Grade <4 D else
    if Grade <5 C else
    if Grade <6 B else
    if Grade ==6 A
```

I think I know how to write the criteria:

```
= IIf([Grade]>2,"F",IIf([Grade]<3,"E",IIf([Grade]<4,"D",IIf([Grade]<5,"C",IIf([Grade]<6,"B","A"))))))
```

But I have a problem with the field name. I tried

```
Grades verbally: "" - works but returns nothing
Grades verbally: [Grade] - data type mismatch
Grades verbally: Null - works but returns nothing
```

What do I do?

Comment: I was thinking `Choose` may also work: `Choose(Grade,"F","E","D","C","B","A")` but _If index is not a whole number, it is rounded to the nearest whole number before being evaluated._  It worked fine on grades 1, 1.5....6.5.  Is there any time that .5 is rounded up?  @Gordons will return A for anything above 6, @Gustav will return @, ?, > and = for 7,8,9 and 10 and my Choose will return Null for anything > 6.5.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use the formula:

```
=Chr(71-Int([Grade]))
```

Comment: This is pretty smart but unfortunately it gets lost in translation. See, in my country A = cel, B = bdb, C = db, D = dst etc. I changed it so that it felt more familiar to anyone outside my country

Comment: Ah, that was too easy but worth trying.

Comment: @AlanKalane: You should add the info from your comment to the question. Gustav 's answer perfectly answers you questions as it stands right now.

Comment: @PhilS y I know I didn't expect this kind of answer, I just wanted something where I could replace the letters with their correspondent names

Comment: Then Gordon's solution will fit.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are not quite correct.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT IIf([Grade] < 2, "F",
           IIf([Grade] < 3, "E",
               IIf([Grade] < 4, "D",
                   IIf([Grade] < 5, "C",
                       IIf([Grade] < 6, "B" , "A")
                      )
                  )
              )
           ) as [Grade Verbally]
```

You should really write this using `SWITCH()`:

```
SELECT SWITCH([Grade] < 2, "F",
              [Grade] < 3, "E",
              [Grade] < 4, "D",
              [Grade] < 5, "C",
              [Grade] < 6, "B",
              [Grade] >= 6, "A"
             ) as [Grade Verbally]
```

Comment: @AlanKalane . . . A comment like that doesn't help.